# SOCKS5 + ассоциация UDP порта

Tags: c++, c, winsock, udp

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь отправить UDP пакет через прокси SOCKS5, но после отправки UDP пакета, не приходит ответ. Подключение делаю в следующем порядке:

1. Отправляю приветствие, с указанием методов подключения.
2. Приходит ответ об успешном подключении.
3. Отправляю команду ассоциации UDP порта
4. Приходит ответ успешной ассоциации с портом прокси
5. Отправляю UDP пакет, но ответа нет

Код:

```
int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    SOCKET hSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    SOCKADDR_IN sockAddr;
    sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("106.186.20.123");
    sockAddr.sin_port = htons(10800);

    connect(hSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr));

    bsSend.Write((BYTE)0x05); // VERSION X'05'
    bsSend.Write((BYTE)0x01); // КОЛ-ВО МЕТОДОВ X'01'
    bsSend.Write((BYTE)0x00); // МЕТОД: БЕЗ АВТОРИЗАЦИИ X'00'

    send(hSocket, (const char *)bsSend.GetData(), bsSend.GetNumberOfBytesUsed(), NULL);
    //printf("< [SEND] len: %d\n%s\n\n", bsSend.GetNumberOfBytesUsed(), DumpMem(bsSend.GetData(), bsSend.GetNumberOfBytesUsed()));
    bsSend.Reset();

    ZeroMemory(byteRecv, sizeof(byteRecv));
    iRespLen = recv(hSocket, (char *)byteRecv, sizeof(byteRecv), NULL);

    // ОТВЕТ
    // ==============
    // ВЕРСИЯ X'05'
    // УСПЕШНО X'00'
    // ==============

    if (iRespLen < 2)
    {
        printf("Proxy not active");
        closesocket(hSocket);
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    //printf("> [RECV] len: %d\n%s\n\n", iRespLen, DumpMem(byteRecv, iRespLen));

    bsSend.Write((BYTE)0x05); // ВЕРСИЯ X'05'
    bsSend.Write((BYTE)0x03); // МЕТОД: АССОЦИАЦИЯ UDP ПОРТА X'03'
    bsSend.Write((BYTE)0x00); // ЗАРЕЗЕРВИРОВАННЫЙ БАЙТ X'00'
    bsSend.Write((BYTE)0x01); // ТИП АДРЕСА: IPv4 X'01'
    bsSend.Write((DWORD)inet_addr(SAMP_IP)); // АДРЕС ЦЕЛЕВОГО СЕРВЕРА - 4 БАЙТА
    bsSend.Write((WORD)htons(SAMP_PORT)); // ПОРТ ЦЕЛЕВОГО СЕРВЕРА - 2 БАЙТА

    send(hSocket, (const char *)bsSend.GetData(), bsSend.GetNumberOfBytesUsed(), NULL);
    //printf("< [SEND] len: %d\n%s\n\n", bsSend.GetNumberOfBytesUsed(), DumpMem(bsSend.GetData(), bsSend.GetNumberOfBytesUsed()));
    bsSend.Reset();

    ZeroMemory(byteRecv, sizeof(byteRecv));
    iRespLen = recv(hSocket, (char *)byteRecv, sizeof(byteRecv), NULL);

    // ОТВЕТ
    // ==============
    // ВЕРСИЯ X'05'
    // УСПЕШНО X'00'
    // ЗАРЕЗЕРВИРОВАННЫЙ БАЙТ X'00'
    // ТИП АДРЕСА X'01'
    // АДРЕС - 4 БАЙТА
    // ПОРТ - 2 БАЙТА
    // ==============

    if (iRespLen < 10)
    {
        printf("Proxy disconnected");
        closesocket(hSocket);
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    //printf("> [RECV] len: %d\n%s\n\n", iRespLen, DumpMem(byteRecv, iRespLen));

    WORD wPortUDP;
    DWORD dwAddressUDP;
    BitStream bsRecv(byteRecv, iRespLen, FALSE);

    bsRecv.IgnoreBits(32);
    bsRecv.Read(dwAddressUDP); // АДРЕС - 4 БАЙТА
    bsRecv.Read(wPortUDP); // ПОРТ - 2 БАЙТА

    // УСТАНОВКА ПОЛУЧЕННОГО АДРЕСА И ПОРТА ДЛЯ ОТПРАВКИ UDP ПАКЕТА

    sockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = dwAddressUDP;
    sockAddr.sin_port = wPortUDP;

    //printf("Opening UDP session to %s with port %d...\n\n", inet_ntoa(sockAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(wPortUDP));

    SOCKET hSocketUDP = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    bsSend.Write((WORD)0x0000); // ЗАРЕЗЕРВИРОВАННЫЕ БАЙТЫ X'0000'
    bsSend.Write((BYTE)0x00); // ФРАГМЕНТ X'00'
    bsSend.Write((BYTE)0x01); // ТИП АДРЕСА: IPv4 X'01'
    bsSend.Write((DWORD)inet_addr(SAMP_IP)); // АДРЕС ЦЕЛЕВОГО СЕРВЕРА - 4 БАЙТА
    bsSend.Write((WORD)htons(SAMP_PORT)); // ПОРТ ЦЕЛЕВОГО СЕРВЕРА - 4 БАЙТА
    bsSend.Write("SAMP", 4); // ДАННЫЕ - 11 БАЙТ
    bsSend.Write((DWORD)inet_addr(SAMP_IP));
    bsSend.Write((WORD)htons(SAMP_PORT));
    bsSend.Write((BYTE)'i');

    sendto(hSocketUDP, (char *)bsSend.GetData(), bsSend.GetNumberOfBytesUsed(), NULL, (SOCKADDR *)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr));
    //printf("< [SENDTO] len: %d\n%s\n\n", bsSend.GetNumberOfBytesUsed(), DumpMem(bsSend.GetData(), bsSend.GetNumberOfBytesUsed()));
    bsSend.Reset();

    // ДАЛЬШЕ КОД НЕ ПРОХОДИТ, ТАК КАК НЕТ ВХОДЯЩЕГО UDP ПАКЕТА

    iRespLen = recvfrom(hSocketUDP, (char *)byteRecv, sizeof(byteRecv), NULL, NULL, 0);
    //printf("> [RECVFROM] len: %d\n%s\n\n", iRespLen, DumpMem(byteRecv, iRespLen));

    if (iRespLen == -1)
    {
        printf("Proxy disconnected");
        closesocket(hSocketUDP);
        closesocket(hSocket);
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    closesocket(hSocketUDP);
    closesocket(hSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Добавлено 27.06.2015**

Как оказалось, до сервера пакет доставляется, но при его попытке ответить, анализатор показывает следующее:
http://cs628016.vk.me/v628016369/6905/NvB28JJJSs0.jpg

В чем заключается моя ошибка? Пробовал с разными прокси серверами.

Comment: А какой ответ вы ожидаете получить?

Comment: Скриншот не видно, пожалуйста, выложите его в другом месте и/или приведите текст сообщения в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Типичные проблемы: либо порт получателя закрыт, либо firewall какой не пускает.